# for loop creating vector r

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to create a function to calculate the Box-Cox transformation in R, where you iterate values of lambda (lambdas) in a formula to maximize L. What I ultimately want is a vector of L, such that for all i in lambda, there is a corresponding L value.

```
y <- c(256,256,231,101,256,213,241,246,207,143,287,240,262,234,146,255,184,161,252,229,283,132,218,113,194,237,181,262,104)
df <- 28
n=29
lambdas <- seq(-3,3,0.001)
L <- c(rep(NA,length(lambdas)))


for(i in lambdas) {
if(i != 0) {
yprime <- (((y^i)-1)/i)
} else 
{   yprime <- log(y)
}
st2 <- var(yprime)
L <- (((-df/2)*(log(st2))) + ((i-1)*(df/n)*(sum(log(y)))))
}
```

What I typically end up with L as a vector of 1, with the final iteration calculated.

Comment: you need to assign into the element of `L` rather than reassigning `L`.  `L[i] <- (((...)))`.  However, a for-loop is not the most "R-ish" way to go about this and I am sure box-cox has already been implemented in a package (`install.packages('MASS')`).

Comment: You aren't doing any indexing on L.  Look at your last line of code - it's just writing over L every time through the loop.  Add an index to make it work `L[someindex] <- blah`

Comment: Yes, the powerTransform will do it in the car package, however, I am trying to demonstrate to my class the lamdba-L relationship. Adding and index number to L (L[i]) creates a vector where the first three elements are different, but the remaining 6000 have the same value.

Comment: @user1649902, note that `lambdas` contains negative values and non integers too. But "correct" usage of `L[i]` requires `i` to be positive integer or similar (see `?'['`), so try `L[i == lambdas]`

Answer (score 1):

Use seq_along to generate an index for `lambdas[]` and `L[]`

```
for(i in seq_along(lambdas)) {
   if(i != 0) {
     yprime <- (((y^lambdas[i])-1)/lambdas[i])
     } else { 
     yprime <- log(y)
              }
   st2 <- var(yprime)
   L[i] <- (((-df/2)*(log(st2))) + ((lambdas[i]-1)*(df/n)*(sum(log(y)))))
 }
plot(L)
```